# D3 - get number of dimensions in radial chart

Tags: d3.js

This is probably a basic selector in D3, but can't find it. I just want to get the count of the number of dimensions (rings) in this radial chart.

http://blockbuilder.org/anonymous/1b5e5b56c33ef5c8840160da3e403105

Counting from the inner most blue ring/circle to the outermost ring (e.g. NodeLinkTreeLayout) the count is 5.

What d3 query or property can I use to get this number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For counting the number of layers, or rings as you called them, you just need to find the `depth` property with the highest value in the data array:

```
var rings = d3.max(partition.nodes(root), function(d){ 
    return d.depth
}) + 1;
console.log("the number of rings is " + rings)
```

Since `depth` is zero-based, I'm adding 1 to the maximum value.

Have a look at the console in the updated blockbuilder: http://blockbuilder.org/anonymous/9ac9d8a21f366202f077393b67239cc3

Comment: Thanks.That's what I needed, d3.maxO.